# Jackson @JsonRawValue for Map's value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following Java bean class with gets converted to JSON using Jackson.

```
  public class Thing {
    public String name;

    @JsonRawValue
    public Map content = new HashMap();
  }
```

`content` is a map who's values will be raw JSON from another source. For example:

```
String jsonFromElsewhere = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }";

Thing t = new Thing();
t.name = "test";
t.content.put("1", jsonFromElsewhere);
```

The desired generated JSON is:

```
{"name":"test","content":{"1":{ "foo": "bar" }}}
```

However using `@JsonRawValue` results in:

```
{"name":"test","content":{1={ "foo": "bar" }}}
```

What I need is a way to specify `@JsonRawValue` for only for the Map's value. Is this possible with Jackson?

Comment: Same issue with `@JsonRawValue List<String>`, and Jackson 2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You could easily create custom `JsonSerializer` to do that though.

Also, maybe rather just use one-off POJO:

```
public class RawHolder {
   @JsonProperty("1")
   public String raw;
}

public class Thing {
   public String name;
   public RawHolder content;
}
```

Comment: I thought about the one-off POJO but my "1" is a sequence number that increases.

Answer (score 7):

As StaxMan points out, it's pretty easy to implement a custom `JsonSerializer`.

```
public class Thing {
    public String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)
    public Map<String, String> content = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, String>> {
    public void serialize(Map<String, String> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: value.entrySet()) {
            jgen.writeFieldName(e.getKey());
            // Write value as raw data, since it's already JSON text
            jgen.writeRawValue(e.getValue());
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```