# Jackson CustomSerializer for specific fields

Tags: java, jackson

I have a requirement to take a document with ~60 fields and map it to a customer schema. Our schema has one field that I have as an array like so:

```
  "documents": [{
    "type": "Resume",
    "url": "https://.s3.amazonaws.com/F58723BD-6148-E611-8110-000C29E6C08D.txt"
  }, {
    "type": "Reference",
    "url": "https://.s3.amazonaws.com/F58723BD-6148-E611-8110-000C29E6C08D.txt"
  }]
```

I need to transform that to:

```
"document1": {"type":"Resume", "https://.s3.amazonaws.com/F58723BD-6148-E611-8110-000C29E6C08D.txt"}
"document2": {"type":"Reference", "url":"https://.s3.amazonaws.com/F58723BD-6148-E611-8110-000C29E6C08D.txt"}
```

I've started a cumstom serializer but would really, really like to not have to write a custom serializer for all 60 fields to just do that one transform. Is there a way to tell jackson to serialize all other fields as normal and use my logic for just this one instance?

I have tried a number of options and keep getting the ever-so-helpful error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

If I could even determine what this means it would be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have the cumstom serializer call the default serializer for all those fields that can undergo default serialization.
See this thread for how to do it [How to access default jackson serialization in a custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056215/how-to-access-default-jackson-serialization-in-a-custom-serializer)

Answer (score 0):

If you create, from the input, a map where the values are a string with raw Json, you can use the custom serializer written by Steve Kuo in [Jackson @JsonRawValue for Map's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113237/jackson-jsonrawvalue-for-maps-value/12116837#12116837)